# Basic PE question about moving a planet.

Tags: energy, potential, propulsion

If you lifted enormous masses (eg. many gigantic rocks) at one point (A) of the planet's equator. Then after 180 degree planet rotation, released the potential energy by lowering the rocks (B). 
(*Alternatively after 90 degree rotation, if there's any importance difference)

Would you not have effectively pushed the planet along the line between point A and B. As if the push came from outer space, outside the planet's reference frame.

Please explain for a layman, why the two actions (lift and lower) do, or do not, result in forward propulsion of the planet.

Comment: It depends on how you remove and put back the mass. Are you flying in a spacecraft and carefully cutting off the piece of mass or are you standing on earth and carrying the mass away while pushing on earth with your feet? I guess it is newton's 3rd law we are concerned here. Just moving mass around will alter some rotational properties like angular velocity but not linear motion properties. Only if some unbalanced forces appear during this process, will a change of linear motion happen

Comment: Lifting off the planet surface such as using a winch and tower as lifting apparatus.

Comment: I thought lifting and lowering the weight at the same point would make no difference. But storing then releasing the stored potential energy 180 degrees later, would add real linear push then pull to the planet.

Comment: Why do you think will the 180 degree rotation cause a difference?

Comment: Lifting the rock from the planet surface, will slightly move the rotating planet away from it in the opposite direction (right?). Then say 90 degrees rotation later, lowering the rocks.Do you not pull the planet and rock together, therefore the planet itself has been moved twice in different directions, in real space position?

Answer (score 3):

The center of mass continues to move at the same velocity. You can see this more easily if you make a setup with just two equal masses, and look at the problem in the center of mass frame. If you push them apart, they will move by equal and opposite amounts; when you bring them back together, they will again move by equal and opposite amounts. This means that if they start with a certain velocity, they end with that same velocity - and that answer doesn't change as you change your frame of reference.

If the masses are unequal, the center of mass will be closer to the heavier object - but the underlying ideas are unchanged. And when the objects rotate, they rotate about their mutual center of mass - not the center of the heavier object. Although it may *look* that way...

Comment: Yes thank you, that explains it very well. Thinking of two canonballs instead of a planet and rock. Can't thank you guys enough for help for a beginner.